# In this phrase I used a period in the quotation, after that should I use a or A?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

In this phrase I used a period in the quotation, after that should I use `a` or `A`?

> Is talking like this: "If you cook something better tomorrow, I’ll eat
> everything." a food war?

Comment: You don't put a period in a quotation if something is going to follow the quotation.

Comment: That's a good question about a phrase that is tough to punctuate.  First - talking is never a food war, a food war is a food war, so the question is not clear from the start.  Mixing a colon, quotation marks, and trailing comment is not common (but not necessarily *wrong*).   I would do it like this.  Are questions like - "If you cook something blah blah" - indicative of a food war?

Comment: Without getting too concerned with the other Parts of the Sentence, the "Core IDEA" is that "In a sentence with a quotation in the middle, the Sentence will start with a Capital and will continue with a lower case after the quotation" which can be seen even in this Example.

Comment: @Prem - your capitalisation is a little odd.

Comment: Agreed !! Now, I tried to edit that comment, but "5 minutes" have gone by and that comment is not editable now : Not able to correct it now ! @MichaelHarvey

Comment: @Prem - you can copy - paste - edit into a new comment and delete the old one.